# MySQL ORDER BY offset

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

In a MySQL query how would I select:

- all rows, ordered by column `name`
- those with `name > 'f'` should come first, then the rest alphabetically

so I'd get `G, H, …, X, Y, Z, A, B, C …, F`.

Comment: no - I'm 35 with kids ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  mytable 
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN name > 'F' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  name
```

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know you could order by a function that was not a result column of the query.  I was going with 
select IF( name >= 'F', 0, 1 ) as PreSort and using THAT as the OrderBy clause

Comment: @monk.e.boy: In MySQL, comparisons result in `0` and `1` directly. This means you *could* get rid of the `CASE` and do `ORDER BY name < 'G', name`, but I find this is much less intuitive (and incompatible to other SQL dialects).

Comment: @Tomalak, agreed, this is the most readable solution. Some of the others are smart but obfuscated :)

Comment: @DRapp: `CASE` is not a function, it is a value returning expression. And you can sort by any value, even if calculated.

Comment: you're right... bad choice of word/intent -- brain cramp with heavy allergy impact slowing down brain synapse connections... dooohhhh :)

Answer (score 2):

Using MySQL, you can use this shorter code:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY name > 'F' DESC, name
```

G,H,I... is greater than F, so the above condition will result to true, true sorts last, false sorts first, so just put DESC

Answer (score 1):

You could make a view with 2 select query's

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name > 'F' ORDER BY name
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name < 'F' ORDER BY name
```

and combine the results

Comment: Little bug: <= not <. There must be a simpler solution using UNION

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it's

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name > 'F' ORDER BY name
```

Comment: you don't get all the rows with that. I need the names starting with A to come after the Zs

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants an answer like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name > 'F' ORDER BY SUBSTR (name, 1, 1) + 'G'
```

Comment: I can't get this to work I get 'FUNCTION anonymous_databse.SUBSTR does not exist'

Comment: Sorry -- I just did some lazy typing and this was meant as a pointer to how you might do it.  I should have said for Oracle, use ORDER BY ASCII('G') + ASCII(SUBSTR (name,1,1))